# ダッシュボードでのアーカイブ

Tags: monaca

以前はBasicプランでもアーカイブ出来ていたのですが、今はアーカイブ出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

現在のFAQには以下のような記述があります。

> **2.11. プロジェクトをアーカイブできません。**
>   プロジェクトのアーカイブ機能は、Personal プラン以上が必要です。
>   <sub>--- http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/faq/environment/#why-i-can-t-archive-my-project より引用</sub>

以下の記事によれば、2014年末に仕様変更されたみたいですね。

http://easyapp.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-264.html